# The eyedropper color chooser disappeared in Chrome Dev Tools v76.0.3809.100

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I just updated to Chrome v76.0.3809.100, and almost immediately found that the Chrome Dev Tools "eyedropper color chooser" functionality no longer works. I don't know if I'm using the right term, but here's what it used to do: inside dev tools, you would inspect an element and click on its color. Immediately an eyedropper-like tool would pop up, and you could then go click on any pixel on the web page and change the inspected element's color to *that* color.

This no longer works. I see there is some kind of new toggle related to eyedropper, and I have tried toggling it, but nothing happens that I can see.

I realize there is still a color palette, but I'm not talking about that. I'm talking about being able to grab any color from the web page by clicking on it, while in "color chooser mode".

This functionality is HUGE, I use it all the time, and now it seems to be GONE.

[image]

Comment: If you're using a High DPI screen, it might be [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=978346). If not, you should probably open a new issue in the [bug tracker](https://crbug.com)

Comment: Bug submitted. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=994744